# Haskell: importing (infix) Data constructors from user added libraries

Tags: haskell

This is a simple question, but I cannot find the way to use the [PSQ library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/PSQueue-1.1/docs/Data-PSQueue.html).

The code below is messy, but seems to find `PSQ` and `fromList`, but fails to find `Binding` (Error: `Not in scope: data constructor 'Data.PSQueue.Binding'`). LearnYouAHaskell does not cover how to use non-standard libraries and I can't find any simple examples that just show PSQ being implemented.

```
import qualified Data.PSQueue (Binding, PSQ, fromList)

{-
data Binding k p
k :-> p binds the key k with the priority p.    
Constructors
k :-> p  

data PSQ k p  
A mapping from keys k to priorites p.
-}

type VertHeap = Data.PSQueue.PSQ Int Int

main = do
    --fromList :: (Ord k, Ord p) => [Binding k p] -> PSQ k p
    return $ Data.PSQueue.fromList $ map (\k -> Data.PSQueue.Binding k 1000000) [2..10]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be easy to miss, but the data constructor for the Binding type is `:->`.

So this import should work:

```
import qualified Data.PSQueue (PSQ,Binding(..),fromList)
```

and later:

```
    return $ Data.PSQueue.fromList $ map (\k -> k Data.PSQueue.:-> 1000000) [2..10]
```

Using `Binding(..)` will import all of the data constructors for the `Binding` data type.

Edit: `:->` is just an infix operator defined by `Data.PSQueue`. `Data.PSQueue.:->` is the fully qualified name for it.

Comment: OK, had no idea `:->` meant something particular (what?). Will I be able to use the rest of the library's functions (e.g. `lookup` and `adjust`) without worrying about `:->` syntax

Comment: updated answer; do you want examples of how to use `lookup` and `adjust`?

Answer (score 0):

Once I understood how to refer to Binding, I could use a more familiar pattern

```
import qualified Data.PSQueue as PSQ
type VertHeap = PSQ.PSQ Int Int
main = do
    return $ PSQ.fromList $ map (\k -> k PSQ.:-> 1000000) [2..10]
```